# Short cut key for expand and collapse block of code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Is there any short cut key for **collapse and expand** all the functions in a file in eclipse?

Comment: what exactly is being asked here? what have you tried or want to do?

Comment: @NirMH Obviously what's asked in the question? Don't know how you'd expand that or what someone could "try" other than smashing the keyboard with your head and looking up (often incomplete) shortcut lists?

Comment: I found the answer for this. For Collapse Ctrl+Shift+NUM_KEYPAD_DIVIDE, For Expand Ctrl+Shift+NUM_KEYPAD_MULTIPLY

Comment: @Mario: after the post was edited, it is clear what is being ask here... a simple help with shortcuts..

Comment: @Lenin: Oh, I see, "you've found the answer". Trying to help you answering at YOUR OWN post worths nothing (neither a "thank you")

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NUM_KEYPAD_DIVIDE</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NUM_KEYPAD_MULTIPLY</kbd> for collapse/expand all respectively.